# Speed up Rails App on development env.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boost, development-environment, performance

I have *huge* Rails app on development right now, which run *VERY* slow on -e development. I use Mongrel as web server. Is there any way to speed up a little bit everything? Because i have to wait 3-10 sec. to reload a page. Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is the answer to all of your woes:

https://github.com/thedarkone/rails-dev-boost

Comment: now I need the same boos for my fingers after sleepless night :)

Comment: No plugin for that, unfortunately :)

Comment: Speed up! when I installed it. Thanks.

Comment: Be very careful with this gem. My team lost tens of hours using this gem.

Comment: What's the principle behind this gem? I can't seem to find a simple explanation in its readme

Comment: Went from 16 seconds to 3 seconds. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to get a speed boost is to turn on class caching in development mode...

In config/environments/development.rb:
    config.cache_classes = true

That means Rails won't reload all the models/controllers/etc. on every request, so it'll go a lot faster, but it means you have to stop/start your server to see changes to anything except views.

Comment: I am in Ubuntu Desktop, and I have the same issues， a simple page load will take more than 2 seconds, when I change config.cache_classes = true, load speed up to 300ms. But what the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The [best way](http://rubyinrails.com/speed-up-rails-in-development-mode/) to make development faster is installing `gem` named `active_reload`.

To install this `gem`, you can enter command,

`gem install active_reload`

And, in your rails project gemfile, add

`gem 'active_reload'`

Then, restart your server and you will find development mode much faster than it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps also some things need some optimising if you are taking 3-10 seconds to render an action locally.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you're on Vista, Mongrel has performance issues when bound to all addresses (0.0.0.0)

Bind to 127.0.0.1 or your real I.P. (mongrel -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e development) and see if it makes a difference.

Also, if you have a connection intensive software currently open, like bittorent with a lot of open connections, your network interface might reach a maximum number of connection and slow down Mongrel. Closing bittorent, then maybe even rebooting, might fix your problem.

Comment: Nope. I'm on MBP with 4GB RAM. As for bittorent. Thank you for that, that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows, use some mingw builds of Ruby
http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

If you're on linux, this might be helpful for running tests

http://github.com/candlerb/snailgun/tree/master

Comment: Are mingw builds faster compared to the ones from one-click installer from ruby-lang.org ?

Comment: on the one-click page you have "RC2" which is mswin (slow, stable) and the "technology preview" versions, which are mingw (faster, newer).